# Get Min and Max values with one MySQL query with Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I've seen similar questions asked here before, but they all seem to be talking about getting only Min **or** Max value. I need to get both, ideally with one query. I can't get my head around the logic how this works in MySQL.
Example data

```
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|temp_min|temp_max|pressure |condition|dt_txt    |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|9.27    |9.27    |1021.98  |Rain     |2018-05-15|
|8.77    |8.77    |1021.22  |Rain     |2018-05-15|
|9.99    |9.99    |1021.31  |Clear    |2018-05-15|
|13.86   |13.86   |1021.41  |Clouds   |2018-05-15|
|12.39   |12.39   |1019.71  |Rain     |2018-05-14|
|13.42   |13.42   |1020.24  |Rain     |2018-05-14|
|14.14   |14.14   |1020.41  |Rain     |2018-05-14|
|9.01    |9.01    |1018.12  |Rain     |2018-05-14|
|13.94   |13.94   |1020.73  |Rain     |2018-05-14|
|5.64    |5.64    |1018.42  |Clouds   |2018-05-14|
|10.65   |10.65   |1021.8   |Clouds   |2018-05-14|
|8.69    |8.69    |1018.91  |Clouds   |2018-05-14|
|...     |...     |...      |...      |...       |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Logic and common sense would dictate something like this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(`temp_min`) AS `temp_min`,
    MAX(`temp_max`) AS `temp_max`,
    `dt_txt`,
    DAYNAME(`dt_txt`) AS `dayname`,
    `pressure`,
    `condition`,
    `dt_txt`
FROM
    infoboard.forecasts
WHERE `dt_txt` >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY `dt_txt`
ORDER BY `dt_txt` ASC;
```

Result is:

```
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+--------+
|temp_min|temp_max|pressure |condition|dt_txt    |        |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+--------+
|10.65   |9.01    |1018.12  |Rain     |2018-05-14|Monday  |
|13.86   |9.99    |1021.98  |Rain     |2018-05-15|Tuesday |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+--------+
```

For `2018-05-14` min should be `8.69` and max should be `14.14`
For `2018-05-15` min should be `8.77` and max should be `13.42`

How do I get real min and max values from temp_* columns and what's the logic that drives the correct query?

Comment: I think GL's answer is very misleading (although, to be fair, it explains why it's misleading). See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Simply fix your data model, storing everything (including `dt_tt`) is plain wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately this query does not really make much sense. Columns pressure and condition need to be removed from the query because their value isn't really defined here. If for the first date temperatures should be 8.69 and 14.14 degrees then there is no common condition and pressure for those two values. Same applies to the next row. If you remove the inadequate columns from the query it should work.

Comment: You're right @rf1234, ignore pressure and condition columns. They're there just for context. I need the min and max temperatures.

Comment: So edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be storing *numeric* values as strings.  You really should fix the data.  But, you can fix the query.  In my opinion, the simplest method is implicit conversion:

```
SELECT MIN(`temp_min` + 0) AS `temp_min`,
       MAX(`temp_max` + 0) AS `temp_max`,
       `dt_txt`, DAYNAME(`dt_txt`) AS `dayname`,
       `pressure`, `condition`, `dt_txt`
FROM infoboard.forecasts
WHERE `dt_txt` >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY `dt_txt`
ORDER BY `dt_txt` ASC;
```

Note that `pressure` and `condition` are not in your `GROUP BY`, so values are chosen from arbitrary rows.  This is a really bad practice, and means that your query would not work in almost any other database.

You can fix the data by doing something like:

```
alter table infoboard.forecasts
    modify column temp_min decimal(6, 3),
    modify column temp_max decimal(6, 3);
```

I suspect you would want to do the same for `pressure` as well.

Comment: Or you can put zero as string before temp_min and temp_max to work correctly

Comment: @HasanGholamali: Why do you think that `010.65` and `09.01` will give a different result?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right I had temperature stored as VARCHAR, I changed those two columns to DECIMAL(3,2) but still the results are the same :/ Then I added "+ 0" and it works! What does this do? How did this make it work? Can you please explain?

Comment: @6bytes: a `DECIMAL(3,2)` can't store values above `9.99`.

Comment: @dnoeth I Mean `10.65` and `09.01`
string number must have the same length to sort in order because they sort character by character like letters

Comment: @6bytes . . . `DECIMAL(3, 2)` is not appropriate for a temperature.  That is why I put in `DECIMAL(6, 3)`.  That will go from -999.999 to 999.999 -- a reasonable range for both Fahrenheit and Celsius for most things humans care about.

Comment: The correct, long-term solution, as Gordon pointed out, is to get the table structure right. This is 1 example of the kind of problem you can run into, when the structure is incorrect.